# Retrieve a table of IDs when their transaction values ​are in a percentile range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get a table of IDs if their transaction values ​​are between the 0.10 and 0.25 percentiles, as follows:

```
select case when transaction_total_value >= percentile_cont(0.10) WITHIN GROUP (order by transaction_total_value) 
                 and transaction_total_value <= percentile_cont(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (order by transaction_total_value) 
            then id_customer 
            else null
        end as id_customer
into tmp_value_4_1
from tmp_value_2_1
group by transaction_total_value,id_customer;
```

But doing this way it returns the entire series of customers ID, not only between the percentiles range.

What I'm doing wrong in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of `tmp_value_2_1` ?

Comment: `id_customer` as text and `transaction_total_value` as bigint

Comment: add where clause to filter out the data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
  select 
    id_customer, 
    transaction_total_value,
    percentile_cont(0.10) within group (order by transaction_total_value asc) as percentile_10,
    percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by transaction_total_value asc) as percentile_25
  from tmp_value_2_1
)
select id_customer 
from cte
where transaction_total_value betweeen 
  percentile_10 and percentile_25
```